# SQL Server stored procedures generator from SQL statement?

Tags: sql-server, generator, clrstoredprocedure

Does anyone know of a freeware to generate SQL Server stored procedure (ie trigger) from a SQL statement?

I mean I don't want the just basic CRUD stored procedures... What I'm looking for is something like this:

Taking a SQL statement like:

```
INSERT INTO TableB (ColumnA, ColumnB...) 
      (SELECT Distinct ValueA,ValueB FROM someTable where someColumn = someValue)
```

And issuing the complete stored procedure statements...

Comment: "complete Stored Procedure statements" is relatively meaningless. Depending on the requirements, a complete stored procedure could be eiter a few lines or a few hundred. (Mild exaggeration.)

Answer (score 1):

Stored procedures and triggers are quite different things.

There are things like [AutoAudit](http://autoaudit.codeplex.com/) which will generate triggers for a table.

Beyond ordinary CRUD, I'm not sure what else you are looking for in a procedure, but it is certainly possible to add it to a code generation template - have a look at the T4 templating engine if your code generation is complex.

Comment: Thanks, but I thought my question was a simple one! Actually, I don't master T-SQL statements, having being years without using it.

Comment: ... And I could spend hours trying to debug a stored procedure when a tool generator can do the job (I suppose) in seconds without errors. Besides, debuggung Transact-SQL far from a simple task.

Comment: @user512602 Your question may be simple to you, but if you gave a concrete example of what you want to start with and what you want it to actually generate, it would be easier to tell what you mean.  In your case, you only give the starting point.  That code (other than the ellipsis) is valid SQL which could simply be wrapped in CREATE PROCEDURE some_proc BEGIN <your code> END, which is why people are downvoting you and voting to close the question.  If you give an example of the target end result and goals, you are more likely to get better answers.